# Avid Media Composer 8 - is it possible to edit two video sessions at same time?

Tags: avid

I am editing multiple interviews of people and there is video, graphic and audio components that are shared between these different interviews.   Is it possible to have two edit sessions running at same time and how

Comment: It isn't really clear what you are hoping to accomplish by having two editing sessions open at the same time.  How are you planning to use two separate sessions simultaneously in your workflow?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about having two projects open at one time? As far as I'm aware, Avid MC doesn't let you do that.

But you can import Bins from another project and technically do what you want that way. Otherwise I would just make one project for all the interviews, and separate them with bins if they're all sharing some elements.

EXP:
Interview1 Bin (containing the clips for interview 1)
Interview2 Bin (containing the clips for interview 2)
SFX (Shared sound effects) 
Music (Shared music) 
GRX  (Shared graphics)